# which file calls validationTextBox.js?

Tags: dojo

Anyone have any idea which dojo file call validationTextbox???If i need to write a customized validationTextbox file , i also have to write a customized file to call this particular one??

Any help is welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own customized ValidationTextBox by extending the ValidationTextBox widget.
The validationTextBox is present in  dojo dir>dijit>form>ValidationTextBox.js